# How to distinguish between connection issues and abort by user in AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

When AJAX call failed with response status 0, 
It possible to distinguish between connection issues and abort by user such as page refresh？
I tried to distinguish it by the following property, but eventually I could not find any solutions.

- XMLHttpRequest#readyState
- XMLHttpRequest#statusText
- XMLHttpRequest#getResponseHeaders()

I referred

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest
- https://ilikestuffblog.com/2009/11/30/how-to-distinguish-a-user-aborted-ajax-call-from-an-error/

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you add some code and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? These help us answer your question better.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. 
but, I think that it is not necessary to add my code because when AJAX call fail due to connection issues or abort by user, it returns status 0, empty statusText and empty response headers etc regardless of my code.

Comment: It might not be necessary, but adding code will increase the likelihood of an answer. Plus, if you're asking how to do something in code, or about a problem with your code, then it is necessary to add code. :D